# How to search a string containing with $ and ; in linux

Tags: unix, awk

I ran a ldapsearch command and the output is redirected to a file(overwriting the same file every time the command is run) I have to search 3 strings, In which have 2 strings have $ and ; in it.

Contents in the file **example.txt**

```
<some lines above>
changenumber;demo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
changenumber;echo$fine-example_good2$host-example_good1
changenumber;echo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
changenumber;demo$fine-example_good2$host-example_good1
<some lines below>
<end of file>
```

**Tried below commands**

```
awk -F";|$" '/echo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2'/ example.txt

awk -F"[$;]" '/demo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2'/ example.txt
```

**Output**: nothing is displayed

**Expected output**

```
changenumber;demo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
changenumber;echo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` has special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape it.

```
awk -F'[;$]' '/demo\$host-example_good1\$fine-example_good2/' example.txt
```

Go to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info) to read a tutorial about regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it worked for me. The link which you have shared for regular expression does not have a valid https url/cert. if there is an alternate website please let me know

Comment: Thanks :) . @Barmar Now I am trying to store the output of the above command in a variable, I have an issue and a doubt

1. I am not able to run the above command in shell script, its giving me blank screen
2. If we can run this command in shell script then how to store it in a variable and print it

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var=$(command)` will store the output of a command in the variable. It should work with the above command.

Answer (score 0):

To search for a **string** use a **string** function, not regexp:

```
$ awk 'index($0,"$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2")' file
changenumber;demo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
changenumber;echo$host-example_good1$fine-example_good2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your command worked as well, can you please throw some insights of your command?

Comment: It prints each line that contains the string. Not sure what else to say about it. Let me know if you have any specific questions after a glance at "index()" in the awk man page.